# Writing to existing file and changing permissions

Tags: perl

I am trying to write to an existing file and at the same time change its permissions. For example:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Slurp 'write_file';

my $script="#! /bin/bash
echo \"Hello\"
";

my $saveName='test.sh';
unlink $saveName if -f $saveName;
writeFile($saveName,$script,0755);
writeFile($saveName,$script,0775);


sub writeFile {
   my ($saveName,$script,$mode) = @_;

   printf "Writing file with permissions %04o\n", $mode & 07777;
   write_file($saveName,{perms=>$mode},\$script);
   my $actualMode = (stat($saveName))[2];
   printf "Actual file permissions are %04o\n", $actualMode & 07777;
}
```

This gives output:

```
Writing file with permissions 0755
Actual file permissions are 0755
Writing file with permissions 0775
Actual file permissions are 0755
```

Why is the permission still `0755` after the second write? (I would expect it to be `0775`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurp#perms):

```
perms

The perms option sets the permissions of newly-created files. This value is 
modified by your process's umask and defaults to 0666 (same as sysopen).
```

Note the word "newly-created".

This behaviour is not dictated by the module, but by the core [`sysopen`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysopen.html). From the source of [`File::Slurp`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurp):

```
                my $perms = $opts->{perms} ;
                $perms = 0666 unless defined $perms ;

#printf "WR: BINARY %x MODE %x\n", O_BINARY, $mode ;

# open the file and handle any error.

                $write_fh = local( *FH ) ;
#               $write_fh = gensym ;
                unless ( sysopen( $write_fh, $file_name, $mode, $perms ) ) {
```

We see that `sysopen` is used. In [the documentation for `sysopen`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysopen.html) it says:

> If the file named by FILENAME **does not exist and the open call creates it** (typically because MODE includes the O_CREAT flag), then the value of PERMS specifies the permissions of the newly created file.

Comment: Thanks, but this seems like a strange approach to me. It means that if you would like to use the option `perms` to `write_file`, you first have to check if the file already exists. If that is the case, you must either explicitly delete it, or use `chmod` after you wrote the file..

Comment: That is not controlled by the module, but by `sysopen`. I will add the documentation to show you.